# How to I merge a Branch back to the Main branch in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I did a Git > Switch/Checkout to an older version of TheFile
I didn't realize this was creating a whole new Branch (NewBranch)
I made modifications to the file.  Now I want to merge that updated file back into the Master branch.

So I did a Switch/Checkout to MASTER then Show Log and show NewBranch and then right-click on TheFile and chose "Merge to Master".

I get a message **Already up-to-date** and Success.

However, the TheFile is not the version from NewBranch.
(I can view Log, and Switch/Checkout to NewBranch and copied that file. So I have a local extra copy of TheFile from NewBranch).

I must be missing something really obvious.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From your description I understand that you want to reset a file to an older state. In Git merging only works on the commit/branch and not on the file level.

For this open the log dialog and select the revision to which you want to reset the file. Then select the file in the lower list of files and click on "Revert to this revision" in the context menu.

Now this file is shown as modified in the working tree and can be committed.

Comment: @ClayNichols If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more information so that I can improve my answer.